# iPhone SDK: Button appears too stretched for iPhone app running on iPad

Tags: iphone

When I try to run my app on the iPad the buttons are too big.

Below is two images One is of the app running on the iPHone sim. The other is the app running on the iPad sim. Notice the button in the iPad apps left hand corner. The button is too big. This is the code I use to create nav buttons.

Any help appreciated.

```
//add back bar button
    UIImage *imageBackBtn;
        UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    imageBackBtn = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonBack.png"]  stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10 topCapHeight:10];   
    [btnBack setBackgroundImage:imageBackBtn forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    [btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(cancel:)  
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnBack.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = NO;
    btnBack.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;


     btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 49, 30);        
    UIBarButtonItem *btnItemCancel = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack] autorelease];  
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnItemCancel;
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check: `-stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` will stretch an image bigger, but won't shrink it down. If your `ButtonBack.png` image is larger than 49x30px, that might be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the bounds of btnBack is getting modified somewhere and is larger than the bounds of the leftBarButtonItem. Try setting up an autoresizing mask for btnBack